# Mongoose - Redefining schema structure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var personSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    address: String,
});

var Person = mongoose.model('humans', personSchema);

var john = Person({ //will turn into a new object.
    firstname: "john",
    lastname: "doe",
    address: "somewhere",

});

//save the user
john.save(function(err){
   if(err) throw err;
   console.log('person saved!'); 
});
```

now, in my database, I have a collection called humans with 
        firstname: "john",
        lastname: "doe",
        address: "somewhere",
as you can see above. My question is: is there a way that inside the humans collection, there will be 1 document that will have the structure you see above, and one with some new fields:

```
firstname: String,
lastname: String,
address: String,
car: String,
office: String
```

I have tried a couple of ways to redefine the structure of the personSchema
but it's always giving me the same error, Cannot overwrite model once compiled.”

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because you already have a schema defined, and then you are defining the schema again. Instantiate the schema once and the make Global object to access schema.

Change your Person schema, and add new fields

```
var personSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    address: String,
    car: String,
    office: String
});
```

Documents which does not contain added fields after populating will have this keys but with undefined values.

For not ignoring new properties you can unstrict schema

```
var personSchema = new Schema({
        firstname: String,
        lastname: String,
        address: String,
        car: String,
        office: String
    }, {strict: false});
```

Also you can use Mixed type to set anything to property

```
var personSchema = new Schema({
            firstname: String,
            lastname: String,
            additional: Mixed
        });
```

And set other properties in additional field.

Comment: I see, but there will be many objects which will have undefined properties, and that takes a little bit space. I thought there was a way to have one document with certain properties and another in the same collection with different properties.

Comment: No undefined properties is not keeping in db.

Comment: Ok, but say later on I want to add  dynamic properties to my document, which I won't be able to tell it's name therefore cannot declare it in advance
. I'll need to redefine my structure, and i don't know how..

Comment: In that case use , {strict: false} as second argument of schema constructor, and you can dynamic add any properties to object, like new Person({'anything', 'anythiong'})

Comment: Also you can use mixed type, but change you Schema like {"additional":Mixed} and set any data in additional filed

Comment: Can you update your answer then with the proper example, thank you.