# Mongoose Node.JS Error Cannot create field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to update an element inside my collection. Its a two dimensional array. I tried directly modifiying it, i tried to update the whole array structure and tried to use the set method. Nothing did give me success.

This is my model:

```
var nestedInside = mongoose.Schema({
    x: Number,
    y: Number,
    block: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }, 
    answer: String,
    question: String,
    questionnr: Number,
    vertical: Boolean,
    questionnr2: Number,
    question2: String,
    vertical2: Boolean,
    tmp: String,
    question_vertical: String,
    question_horizontal: String,
    question_num: Number
})

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    grid: [[nestedInside]]
})

var create = mongoose.model('puzzles', schema);
```

This is my error when i do the following code:

```
puzzle.findOne({_id:req.params.id}).exec(function(err,data) {
   var grid = data.grid;
   grid[req.body.xo].id(req.body._id)["question_vertical"] = req.body.question_vertical
   data.save();
```

```
errorMongoError: Cannot create field 'question_vertical' in element {0: [ { block: false, _id: ObjectId('5dec2f1dde95855cf9130f50')...
```

When i try to replace the whole array it says: Cast to Array failed for value

Anyone any idea? I'm out of options which i know.

sample data:

```
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5da1097076a05f2c50f34001"
   },
   "free":false,
   "package":{
      "$numberInt":"6"
   },
   "grid":[
      [
         {
            "block":false,
            "_id":{
               "$oid":"5da1097076a05f2c50f34008"
            },
            "x":{
               "$numberInt":"1"
            },
            "y":{
               "$numberInt":"1"
            },
            "answer":"G",
            "question_num":{
               "$numberInt":"1"
            },
            "question_vertical":"Abk.: Grundgesetz",
            "question_horizontal":"kostenlos"
         },
    ....
       ]
    ],
    ....
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample document

Comment: i added it to my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured out a solution, or lets say a workaround.

I clone the whole document, delete the old one and save the cloned document again. This worked fine. Just for someone who maybe gets the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you updated your array structure. Did you delete the old items from the database (or even better deleted the current database)? Otherwise this could lead to wrong document parsing ([Mongoose - Redefining schema structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35819596/mongoose-redefining-schema-structure)).

Comment: The Schema wasn't changed at any point, it was the same the whole time. I just take one element of the array and change one value, which is already there. I logged the the element before to check, if its populated. Then i change the String Value and afterwards while saving the error occurs.